# Conditional Formatting a textbox

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-expression

I'm using ReportBuilder

Below is an expression to change the background color based on a value in a cell.  I would like to add a new condition to the existing expression to change textbox22 if it has 'N/A' in it to Light Green

```
=iif(isnothing(reportitems!Textbox22.value),Nothing, switch(reportitems!Textbox22.value >1 and reportitems!Textbox22.value <=50,"#fd6767",reportitems!Textbox22.value >=51 and reportitems!Textbox22.value <=79,"#f8d3a9",reportitems!Textbox22.value >=80 and reportitems!Textbox22.value <=100,"LightGreen",reportitems!Textbox22.value = 0, "#fd6767"))
```

This is the design view

[image]

This is the expression in the cell which brings back "N/A" if there is no value for that cell.

```
=iif(isnothing(lookup(Fields!StatID.value,Fields!statID.value,Fields!pass_rate.value,"Res2nd")),"N/A",lookup(Fields!StatID.value,Fields!statID.value,Fields!pass_rate.value,"Res2nd"))
```

This is the output

[image]

I've tried the below but this makes all the cells white

```
 =switch(reportitems!Textbox22.value >1 and reportitems!Textbox22.value <=50,"#fd6767",reportitems!Textbox22.value >=51 and reportitems!Textbox22.value <=79,"#f8d3a9",reportitems!Textbox22.value >=80 and reportitems!Textbox22.value <=100,"LightGreen",reportitems!Textbox22.value = 0, "#fd6767",reportitems!Textbox22.value = "N/A","LightGreen")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this working eventually by using the below

```
=iif(reportitems!Textbox22.value >=0 and reportitems!Textbox22.value <=50 ,"#f1b1b1",iif(reportitems!Textbox22.value >50 and reportitems!Textbox22.value <=79,"#f8d3a9","LightGreen"))
```

Answer (score 0):

amend your expression to:

```
=iif(isnothing(reportitems!Textbox22.value),Nothing, switch(reportitems!Textbox22.value >1 and reportitems!Textbox22.value <=50,"#fd6767",reportitems!Textbox22.value >=51 and reportitems!Textbox22.value <=79,"#f8d3a9",reportitems!Textbox22.value >=80 and reportitems!Textbox22.value <=100,"LightGreen",reportitems!Textbox22.value = 0, "#fd6767",reportitems!Textbox22.value ="N/A","LightGreen"))
```

Comment: Thanks @SuperSimmer 44, unfortunately it doesn't work, all the cells return white. It's actually a way I'd already tried as in my mind that makes perfect sense.  I've tried so many variations I'm kind of losing hope.

Comment: As your expression will always bring back a value or "N/A" you could remove the isnothing part of your background colour expression as this part should never be true. It may help???

Comment: Afraid that doesn't work either, I've put the expression above, I'm assuming that's what you meant?

Comment: @Clem_Fandango would you like to send me the .rdl of your report to my email address and i will investigate further?

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

```
=switch(reportitems!Textbox22.value >=0 and reportitems!Textbox22.value <=50,"#fd6767",reportitems!Textbox22.value >=51 and reportitems!Textbox22.value <= 79,"#f8d3a9",reportitems!Textbox22.value >=80 or reportitems!Textbox22.value  = "N/A","LightGreen")
```

Comment: I'm afraid that just turns everything white